# Are colors and size encoded in a digital image?

Tags: printing, color

I have professional pics taken and provided by photographer on CD to be printed at my discretion. Some of my pics get cropped and the colors are way off. Are the colors and printable image type / size encoded in a digital image that some printers can't interpret? Are there images that can only be printed by high quality print labs as opposed to drug store / retail printers?

Comment: I'm curious how the colors are way off. Only some? Color calibrated screen? Are you looking at the non-processed vs the processed images perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you are having trouble getting prints that match what you see when you view the images from the CD on your screen.

The color and the aspect ratio concerns are two separate issues.

**Color** - It is possible your monitor is properly displaying the colors and the printer is not printing them correctly. It is also possible that your monitor is not displaying the colors correctly and the printer is printing them correctly. It is even possible both your monitor and the printer are incorrect but in different ways! Making sure that a monitor or printer displays the correct colors designated in a photo is known as [*color management*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-management).

**Sizes** - There are many different aspect ratios at which photos can be produced, cropped, viewed, and printed. Many of the most common printing sizes of photos have different [*aspect ratios*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aspect-ratio). The aspect ratio is the ratio between the long and short sides of a photograph.

Most cameras take pictures at either a 3:2 or 4:3 aspect ratio.

Common print sizes often have different aspect ratios: 4x6/6x4 (3:2 or 1.5:1), 8x10/10x8 (5:4 or 1.25:1), 7x5/5x7 (7:5 or 1.4:1), 11x14/14x11 (14:11 or 1.27:1). Less common print sizes include 8x12/12x8, 18x12/12x18, 24x16/16x24 (3:2 or 1.5:1), 16x20/20x16 (5:4 or 1.25:1). Dedicated photo print labs often have a greater selection of print sizes available than drug/retail stores will typically offer.

Notice than none of the common print sizes or even the additional ones most often offered by printers fit the 4:3 or 1.33:1 ratio that may cameras natively shoot. This ratio matches the ratio of older standard definition televisions. It is also the ratio of many early computer monitors that had 1024x768 or 640x480 resolution.

When a printer gets a request for a print that is in a different aspect ratio than the photo provided they normally crop the photo so that the print has no empty white areas. If you have a 3:2 photo and you order a 10x8 print the printer will usually print at a magnification that would fill an 8x12 sheet of photo paper and crop one inch off each end of the long side.

At drug/retail stores this is often done automatically by the machine making the print. At a dedicated photo print lab it may be done automatically, it may be done by the operator of the printer based on an inspection of the image and the operator's artistic judgement, or it may even be done by the customer at the time they place the order.